# matplotlib graphs with different size variables

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm quite new to python and am working on an assignment.  I am using pandas to read a csv into a dataframe.  One of the fields in that dataframe is Car-Type. I want to get a total of each of the different Car-Types (sedan, hatch-back, wagon, etc.) in the data frame, then use matplotlib to make graphs of the Car-Types vs. the type-totals.  Depending on the type of graph I try to make, I get different errors about the x and y variables.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

path_to_csv = r'C:\Automobile_data.csv'

# use pandas to read the csv and assign it to a variable, df
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv, encoding='iso-8859-1')

# Where the car-type value is null, set the value to Not Available
df.loc[df['Car-Type'].isnull(), 'Car-Type'] = 'Not_Available'

# create new dataframe with just the car-type counts
countType = df['Car-Type'].value_counts().astype('int64')
print(countType)

# use matplotlib to create a graph
# assign values to the x and y variables
x = df['Car-Type']
y = countType
# create a graph with x and y
plt.plot(x, y)
# # display the graph
plt.show()
```

line: (plt.plot) - ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (205,) and (6,)
bar: (plt.bar) - ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
scatter: (plt.scatter) - ValueError: x and y must be the same size

I understand that there's an error regarding the size and or shape of the data I'm assigning to the x and y variable, but I'm not experienced enough, and haven't been able to extrapolate from reading, how to fix those errors.

Comment: You need some sort of groupby for x based on the value counts. That way your x and y will have same dimensions. Try looking for group by value counts in pandas

Comment: What happens if you use `plt.plot(countType)`? Else, try `plt.plot(countType.index, countType.values)`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, plt.plot(countType) worked for the line graph (and pie chart), which satisfies the requirement for this assignment.  I have another that also requires a bar graph.  Thanks so much for the hint... I can't believe it was that simple.